# Play Services LocationClient Altitude

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have noticed some times the `Location#getAltitude()` returns `0.0` and some others it returns actual data. I have searched through the documentation found in http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html but haven't found about it.

Is it know the reason that sometimes it returns 0? 
Does the `LocationClient#setInterval(int)` and `LocationClient#setFastestInterval(int)` set values affect on this?